# App that allows me to do an in-app image search

Tags: android, images, search

Scenario: I am using Google Keep for notes. I took a photo of a product that I want to get in the future. However, I would prefer to use a better image than what I took, so I want to download an image of the product from the web. I COULD go onto Chrome, do a Google image search, download the image, upload it locally, and then delete the downloaded image.

Then I got to thinking that there's got to be an app that allows me to choose an image. When I use the Choose Image over Camera, it gives me a selection of apps, including Gallery, Dropbox/Carousel, etc. Now I just need one in the list that allows me to choose an image from the Web.

Funny, I tried a couple top image search apps, but they don't seem to be options when you choose an app for images.

Do you know of any decent apps that will do this?

Comment: Not the proper solution, but an alternative. You can use google keyboard when taking notes and tap the google icon and do an Image search, it will paste the URL for the image there itself in the notes. You can use the URL for reference. But it definitely wont let you copy the image from the search right over there. I will think of alternatives and let you know :)

Comment: Did you ever find something? If so, could you share it, please?

Comment: I have not yet, but I'll post if and when I do.

Answer (score 1):

From the browser, I have been using [TinEye](https://services.tineye.com) for many years. Give it an image, or an image URL, and it returns details of all web pages containing that image, which you can sort by size, etc

It has [an API](https://services.tineye.com/TinEyeAPI) which claims "Fast search through billions of images" and "Find heavily cropped and modified versions of images" among others.

> Hosted API
>
> The TinEye API is a fully hosted API. There is no software to install
>   and no updates to worry about. By using our hosted API, you save time
>   and money needed to build and maintain your own image recognition
>   solutions. Easy to integrate
>
> The TinEye API is easily integrated with your existing technology,
>   regardless of the languages and tools you use. Fully documented
>
> The TinEye API is a REST-based API, delivered over HTTP or HTTPS in
>   JSON format. REST/JSON bindings are available in all major programming
>   languages. We also support a growing number of language-specific
>   libraries to make integration very straight forward. Our [documentation](https://services.tineye.com/developers/tineyeapi/)
>   and [libraries](https://services.tineye.com/developers/tineyeapi/libraries.html) are extensive. Scalable and high performance
>
> Multiple image query support including JPEG, PNG, or GIF. Query images
>   can be specified by a publicly accessible image URL, or uploaded.
>   Large and growing image index
>
> The TinEye API searches the TinEye index which is an index of a large
>   cross section of the web. The TinEye index is at 25,462,149,173 images
>   today. Proven technology
>
> Built by TinEye's image recognition scientists and backed by a decade
>   of research and development, the TinEye API is the ideal reverse image
>   search solution for image search and verification.

It is not [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), but you don't ask for that. It starts form 1 cent per search, up to 4 cents per search.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ImageSearcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jhdev.imagesearch&hl=en) plugin by Steven Schoen from Play Store. It works well. Sometimes it will show API error depending on its mood. But still better than nothing.